# Strange Python Pandas read_sql_query() behaviour with specific numbers as params

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, import

I'm importing data from a sqlite database into pandas using a jupyter notebook and have a strange behaviour for specific values as params. I try to read in and control for errors by this code:

```
start_id = 1
end_id = a    

df_input = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT * FROM table WHERE id>? AND id<?""", conn, params={start_id,end_id})
    print("Number of entries to match:", len(df_input))
    print(type(df_input))
```

If I set end_id to 999 or 1001, I get the following result:

```
Number of entries to match: 997
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

and

```
Number of entries to match: 999
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

but if I set end_id to 1000, 10000, 100000

```
Number of entries to match: 0
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
params={start_id, end_id}
```

Why are you using a set? This causes the arguments to be passed to the query in an arbitrary order. This will sometimes create the non-sensical query `id>end_id AND id<start_id`.

You should be using a tuple:

```
params=(start_id, end_id)
```